# Table of Contents - font used for page number and removing/customising 'Contents' title

Tags: fonts, table-of-contents

I've used this site to find how to remove section numbering, and to put my table of contents into two columns, however there is one thing I want to do.

My table of contents currently says 'Contents' at the top. If I want to remove this, or use my own heading, how do I do this?

My document is set up as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2cm, outer=1cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twocolumntoc}{%
  \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{%\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\begin{document}
% set font for entire document
\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont
\twocolumntoc
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer depends on the used class and packages related to the table of contents. So without a [minimal but working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that gives us such essential informations, the question is quiet broad. And please ask only one question per question!

Comment: @Schewinebacke Removed a question, and included a MWE as requested. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please make your example compilable!

Answer (score 2):

Your example is not compiling without error, because of misplaced comment char `%`. But I seems you are searching either

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2cm, outer=1cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twocolumntoc}{%
%  \chapter*{\contentsname
%    \@mkboth{%\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\begin{document}
% set font for entire document
\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont
\twocolumntoc
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Or

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2cm, outer=1cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{This is my contents heading}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twocolumntoc}{%
  \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\begin{document}
% set font for entire document
\fontfamily{qhv}\selectfont
\twocolumntoc
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Note: Redefining `\contentsname` in the document preamble does not work as shown above, if you are using [`babel`](https://ctan.org/pkg/babel). See the `babel` manual for more information about changing language depending terms.

BTW: Setting a sanserif font for the entire document shouldn't be done using `\fontfamily` at the beginning of the document. This would not change the font of elements, that use `\normalfont`. You should instead redefine `\familydefault`. `qhv` is TeX Gyre Heros. There is a package to use it. So you can use:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, twocolumn]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2cm, outer=1cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}% use TeX Gyre Heros for entire documente

\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{This is my contents heading}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\twocolumntoc}{%
  \chapter*{\contentsname
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
  \@starttoc{toc}%
}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\begin{document}
\twocolumntoc
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Additional note because of a comment: If you do not use `\chapter*` in your document, you are using the wrong class. In this case, `article` instead of `book` would be better and you wouldn't need `\twocolumntoc`:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, inner=2cm, outer=1cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}% use TeX Gyre Heros for entire documente

\renewcommand*{\contentsname}{This is my contents heading}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}% Don't use section numbering
\usepackage{mwe}% useful only for demonstration

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: using article]

Comment: Excellent - I didn't even know changing the font for the entire document. Works well.

I have included the contents name, but how do I change the size of the font used for it, so it is consistent with other headings in the document?

Comment: @C.deHaer Aren't you using `\chapter` for headings? Then you are using the wrong class. Using `article` makes things very, very easy in this case. See the last example in the edited answer.